# manipulating a list of tags (.lstrip()), nested with in a dictionary, nested within a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask, text-processing

I am getting myself all tangled up where in the nesting.

I have a list of python objects that look like this:

```
notes = [
     {'id':1,
      'title':'title1',
      'text':'bla1 bla1 bla1',
      'tags':['tag1a', ' tag1b', ' tag1c']},
     {'id':2,
      'title':'title2',
      'text':'bla2 bla2 bla2',
      'tags':[' tag2a', ' tag2b', ' tag2c']},
     {'id':3,
      'title':'title3',
      'text':'bla3 bla3 bla3',
      'tags':[' tag3a', ' tag3b', ' tag3c']}]
```

and so on.

I am trying to go into each dictionary in the list and strip out the left whitespaces and return a list of dictionaries where the only difference are the tags have their uneccessary white space stripped.

The following code is what I am working with, but it is not right and I don't know what I am doing to get to the result i need.

```
notes_cleaned = []
for objs in notes:
    for items in objs:
        notes_cleaned.append({'text':n['text'], 'id':n['id'], 'tags':[z.lstrip(' ') for z in n['tags']], 'title':n['title']})
```

Which gives me an error that i can't use string indexes, which I understand, but I don't know how to do it right. since I know that I have to iterate over each dictionary like:

```
for objs in notes:
    for items in objs:
        print items, objs[items]
```

but I am confused as to how to get to the final part of rebuilding the dictionaries while digging into the tag lists specifically.

What am I missing here (knowing that I am definitely missing something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code *should* work, assuming only "tags" needs to be stripped:

```
def clean(items):
    clean = []
    for objs in items:
        nObj = {}
        for item, obj in objs.iteritems():
            if item != "tags":
                nObj[item] = obj
            else:
                nObj["tags"] = [n.lstrip() for n in obj]
        clean.append(nObj)
    return clean
```

Comment: thanks, this is the most explicit explanation so I've chosen this one.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is enough:

```
for note in notes:
    note['tags']= [t.strip() for t in note['tags']]
```

If you *really* need to operate on a copy (of notes), you can get it easily: `copy= map(dict, notes)`

Comment: Note that `map(dict, notes)` will only make a shallow copy of `notes` -- they'll share the `tags` lists.

Comment: @DSM Yes, that's mention-worthy if you want to do something else with the list, though it doesn't apply if you do so after the `for`, since the list is recreated.

Comment: had not considered map(), but cool. also, very straight forward code thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    python 3.2

     # if you want the dict which value is list and string within the list stripped 

     [{i:[j.strip() for j in v] for i,v in k.items()if isinstance(v,list)} for k in notes]



     # if you want the dict which value is list and those string within the list 
    stripped which has whitespace

     [{i:[j.strip() for j in v if " " in j] for i,v in k.items()if isinstance(v,list)}
                   for k in n]
```

Comment: suppose I should have added I am still on python 2.7, but this is still helpful. Thank you!